# How to test gestures with Selenium using ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, gesture

Based on the [Mobile Emulation
 documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation) and [TouchActions Class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/) I come up with the following code but I got exception: `The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen.`

```cs
namespace Example
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

    [TestClass]
    public class ExampleTest
    {
        IWebDriver chromeDriver;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.EnableMobileEmulation("Nexus 6P"); // Allows the Chrome browser to emulate a mobile device.
            chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTestMethod()
        {
            chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");
            IWebElement link = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a"));

            // Threw exception:
            // The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen.
            var touchActions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.TouchActions(chromeDriver);

            touchActions
                .SingleTap(link)
                .Build()
                .Perform();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            chromeDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the documentation but there is no info about how to enable touch gestures on `ChromeDriver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `ChromeDriver` does not have `TouchScreen` by default.
We need to create a new class to support it, just need to implement `IHasTouchScreen` interface, with `RemoteTouchScreen` class.

```cs
namespace Example
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

    public class ChromeDriverWithTouchScreen : ChromeDriver, IHasTouchScreen
    {
        public ITouchScreen TouchScreen => new RemoteTouchScreen(this);

        public ChromeDriverWithTouchScreen(ChromeOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class ExampleTest
    {
        IWebDriver chromeDriver;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.EnableMobileEmulation("Nexus 6P"); // Allows the Chrome browser to emulate a mobile device.
            chromeDriver = new ChromeDriverWithTouchScreen(chromeOptions);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTestMethod()
        {
            chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");
            IWebElement link = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a"));

            // Threw exception:
            // The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen.
            var touchActions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.TouchActions(chromeDriver);

            touchActions
                .SingleTap(link)
                .Build()
                .Perform();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            chromeDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is no longer a valid solution. IHasTouchScreen and ITouchScreen are deprecated. The recommendation is to use TouchActions or ActionBuilder classes

Comment: @Kbam7 If you do not implement it, it will arise an exception! so if you implements the class as Peter says, it will work like a charm!

Comment: @Kbam7: No mentions about deprecate in [ITouchScreen Interface](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_ITouchScreen.htm) and [IHasTouchScreen](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IHasTouchScreen.htm)

Comment: Those docs aren't the best. I don't think they are actively maintained either. When using the code from @Peter I get deprecation warnings. I decompiled the dll with JetBrains decompiler and in the code it is clearly marked with an obsolete attribute. [See here](https://pasteboard.co/IAdVOip.png)

Comment: This is still the correct answer. In the latest stable release, the constructor of TouchActions [will throw](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/TouchActions.cs#L56) if the driver doesn't implement IHasTouchScreen, so it must be used, though marked as deprecated. In the upcoming version 4, [it will be gone](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG#L142).